# how to plot matrices with ggplot2 and maintain the same colors for the same values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot values stored in 12 matrices. Each matrix cell can contain a number from 1 to 10, and I use ggplot2 to plot these values with:

```
col<-c("red", "orange", "blue", "cyan", "green", "lightgreen", "violet", "pink", "black", "brown")
tdm <- melt(node10den0.7)
ggplot(tdm, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = factor(value))) +
labs(x = "Cost", y = "Benefit", fill = "Value", title="10 nodes, den=0.7") +
geom_raster() +
scale_fill_manual("Legend", breaks = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"),
                  values = col, labels=c("null", "n-null", "star", "n-star", "bistar", "n-bistar", "shared", "n-shared", "complete", "n-complete")) +
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"),
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90")) +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

My problem is that not all the matrices contain all the possible values, so I see there is a shift of colors for some values in some of the plots... Is there a way to keep color fixed? like if you see 2 in the matrix then plot it red?

Second question: Is it possible to make ggplot2 display all the possible colors/labels in the legend?

I add a couple of my matrices as example:

```
> dput(node3den0)
structure(c(2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 2, 0, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 
0, 0, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), .Dim = c(19L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(
c("0.05", "0.1", "0.15", "0.2", "0.25", "0.3", "0.35", "0.4", 
"0.45", "0.5", "0.55", "0.6", "0.65", "0.7", "0.75", "0.8", 
"0.85", "0.9", "0.95"), c("0.05", "0.1", "0.15", "0.2", "0.25", 
"0.3", "0.35", "0.4", "0.45", "0.5", "0.55", "0.6", "0.65", 
"0.7", "0.75", "0.8", "0.85", "0.9", "0.95")))

> dput(node10den0.7)
structure(c(3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 7, 0, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 2, 
0, 0, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 2, 0, 
0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
10, 3, 7, 7, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 10, 
10, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
2, 3, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 10, 10, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 10, 10, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 10, 3, 2, 10, 3, 2, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
2, 10, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 3, 3, 2, 3, 10, 2, 3, 10, 
3, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 10, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
10, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 10, 10, 2, 10, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 10, 2, 
7), .Dim = c(19L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(c("0.05", "0.1", "0.15", 
"0.2", "0.25", "0.3", "0.35", "0.4", "0.45", "0.5", "0.55", "0.6", 
"0.65", "0.7", "0.75", "0.8", "0.85", "0.9", "0.95"), c("0.05", 
"0.1", "0.15", "0.2", "0.25", "0.3", "0.35", "0.4", "0.45", "0.5", 
"0.55", "0.6", "0.65", "0.7", "0.75", "0.8", "0.85", "0.9", "0.95"
)))
```

Best regards,
Simone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `limits` argument. With your first matrix:

```
col<-c("red", "orange", "blue", "cyan", 
       "green", "lightgreen", "violet", "pink", "black", "brown", "yellow")
ggplot(tdm, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = factor(value))) +
  labs(x = "Cost", y = "Benefit", fill = "Value", title="10 nodes, den=0.7") +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", limits = 0:10,
                    values = col, 
                    labels=c("null", "n-null", "star", "n-star", "bistar", 
                      "n-bistar", "shared", "n-shared", "complete", "n-complete",
                      "additional")) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Note that I added one colour value because your possible values seem to go from 0 to 10.

Comment: I had however a comment: your plot seems to be nicely square, while on my computer x and y axes does not look like having the same length...

Comment: @SimoneGabbriellini That depends on the size of your graph window. Use `ggsave` to save the plot with defined dimensions.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to use ggsave, but on my mac osx this produces  pretty bad pdfs... on screen, everything is perfect, but when saved only axes and legend are crispy clear, all the other stuff is blurred...

Comment: I've never had this problem on my mac at home, but you could try to use a different pdf device.

Comment: solved this, it was a problem with Preview settings... thanks